# Which C# driver to use for Mongo?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am starting a new project using Mongo and was wondering what the general consensus is on which C# driver to use?

I am leaning towards NoRM ([here](https://github.com/atheken/NoRM#readme)) or the official driver ([here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Language+Center)).

Any suggestions or opinions on which to use and what to consider when deciding?

I realize there are other questions on this topic but they are somewhat dated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NoRM has some cool features, but it is not actively maintained any more.  Sure that may change but I would rather go with the one that is being actively developed.

I switched my application over to the officlal C# driver and its been great - its been updated to take advantage of all the new features of 1.8 and will continue to be upgraded to take advantage of new MongoDB features as they come out.

Comment: I agree with you but I wish it supported Linq and IQueryable

Comment: There is a library called FluentMongo that you might want to look into.  I have not used it myself so I cannot say for sure if it does what you want or not.  I know there are also some tickets in Jira for LINQ support, which I suspect will eventually be addressed because it really makes for a very powerful API.

Comment: Thank you for the reference to FluentMongo. It's good enough to allow me to expose an IQueryable interface which is great.

Comment: @rboarman the 1.4 version has been released and has LINQ support so you can transition out of FluentMongo.

Answer (score 5):

Use mongodb c# driver. Because official mongodb c# driver is well tested, contains all latest features of mongodb and supported by community.

Linq? Do you think it's a real problem? I guess no. I found [jira bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-91) for linq support, but is without votes.. In additional i've using official mongodb c# driver at all my projects and it work very well even without linq.

*So, my opinion is that no need to think, need just use official mongodb c# driver.*